# conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, resnet

**Error message**
*TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple!, !tuple!, !tuple!, int)*

***Block code***

```
class blocks(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channel, out_channel, stride=1, downsample=None):
    super(blocks,self).__init__()
    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channel,out_channel,kernel_size=3,stride=stride,padding=1)
    self.batchnorm1=nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channel)
    self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(out_channel,out_channel,kernel_size=3,padding=1,stride=1)
    self.batcnorm2=nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channel)
    self.relu=nn.ReLU()
    self.identity_downsample=downsample
  def forward(self,x):
    identity=x
    x=self.conv1(x)
    x=self.batchnorm1(x)
    x=self.relu(x)
    x=self.conv2(x)
    x=self.batchnorm1(x)
    if self.identity_downsample is not None:
      identity=self.identity_downsample(x)
    x=x+identity
    x=self.relu(x)
    return x
```

***Resnet Code***

```
class ResNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,block,layers,num_classes=136):
    super(ResNet,self).__init__()
    self.in_channels = 64
    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(3,self.in_channels,kernel_size=7,padding=1)
    self.norm1=nn.BatchNorm2d(self.in_channels)
    self.relu=nn.ReLU()
    self.layer1=self.layers(block,64,layers[0])
    self.layer2=self.layers(block,124,layers[1],stride=2)
    self.layer3=self.layers(block,256,layers[2],stride=2)
    self.layer4=self.layers(block,512,layers[3],stride=2)
    self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
    self.linear_classifier1=nn.Linear(512,256)
    self.linear_classifier2=nn.Linear(256,num_classes)
  def layers(self,block,out_channels,no_of_blocks,stride=1):
    downsample=None
   
    if stride!=1 or self.in_channels!=out_channels:
      downsample=nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(self.in_channels,out_channels,kernel_size=1,stride=stride),
          nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
      )
    layers=[]
    layers.append(block(self.in_channels,out_channels,downsample,stride))
    self.in_channels=out_channels
    for i in range(1,no_of_blocks):
      layers.append(block(self.in_channels,out_channels))
    
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

  def forward(self,x):
    x=self.conv1(x)
    x=self.norm1(x)
    x=ff.max_pool2d(x,kernel_size=3,stride=2,padding=1)
    x=self.relu(x)
    x=self.layer1(x)
    x=self.layer2(x)
    x=self.layer3(x)
    x=self.layer4(x)   
    x=self.avgpool(X)
    x=x.linear_layer1(x)
    x=self.relu(x)
    x=ff.dropout(x,0.4)
    x=self.linear_classifier2(x)
    x=ff.sigmoid(x)         
    return x
```

***Training loop***

```
train_loss, test_loss = [], []
n_epochs = 50

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    print(f" epoch {epoch+ 1} : 50")
    epoch_train_loss, epoch_test_loss = 0, 0
    for ix, (img,kps) in enumerate(train_loader):
        loss = train_batch(img, kps, model, optimizer, criterion)
        epoch_train_loss += loss.item() 
    epoch_train_loss /= (ix+1)

    for ix,(img,kps) in enumerate(test_loader):
        ps, loss = validate_batch(img, kps, model, criterion)
        epoch_test_loss += loss.item() 
    epoch_test_loss /= (ix+1)

    train_loss.append(epoch_train_loss)
    test_loss.append(epoch_test_loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter order is not same as the block class while you are creating the instance.

block(self.in_channels,out_channels,downsample,stride)